How to capture custom metadata in PaperTrail only on create event type and work normally for update and destroy
has_paper_trail on: [:create], meta: { object: "custom data" }
this works only for create event
has_paper_trail on: [:create], meta: { object: "custom data" }
has_paper_trail on: [:update, destroy]

tried this way for other events apart from create
but second call overrides the first here
i need custom data only incase of create and and other events should work normally

it works for create event but not for other events

But the question is identical

Try using a lambda that only returns data for meta when the object is a new record...
has_paper_trail on: [:create, :update, :destroy], 
                meta: Proc.new { |t| t.new_record? ? { object: "custom data" } : nil }


nil creates empty record but we need to have previous data in object field

then update the code accordingly
